# Firefox WebIDE can't install app on Android Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, firefox, web-ide

I'm trying the new Firefox Developer Edition. I'm struggling to get the WebIDE to run a project in my smartphone. In the documentation, it's said you can debug an app using Chrome 37+ on android. When I connect it to my mac, I can get the WebIDE to recognize the device, but when I try to run it, I get this error: "Operation failed: installing and running app: Can't install". What am I missing?

I already setup developer mode on android and turned on debugg usb mode.

Thanks in advance!